# python pandas select both head and tail

Tags: python, pandas, slice, tail, head

For a DataFrame in Pandas, how can I select both the first 5 values and last 5 values?

For example

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
        A  B  C
2012-11-29  0  0  0
2012-11-30  1  1  1
2012-12-01  2  2  2
2012-12-02  3  3  3
2012-12-03  4  4  4
2012-12-04  5  5  5
2012-12-05  6  6  6
2012-12-06  7  7  7
2012-12-07  8  8  8
2012-12-08  9  9  9
```

How to show the first two and the last two rows?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense, you state you want to select first 5 values and last 5 values, are you referring to rows or individual values? Please show the desired output

Comment: In addition to the other values, head and tail can be chained (like in bash :) to give you a values in the middle (df.head(90).tail(10)) to get values 80 to 90

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
print (np.r_[0:2, -2:0])
[ 0  1 -2 -1]

df = df.iloc[np.r_[0:2, -2:0]]
print (df)
            A  B  C
2012-11-29  0  0  0
2012-11-30  1  1  1
2012-12-07  8  8  8
2012-12-08  9  9  9
```

---

```
df = df.iloc[np.r_[0:4, -4:0]]
print (df)
            A  B  C
2012-11-29  0  0  0
2012-11-30  1  1  1
2012-12-01  2  2  2
2012-12-02  3  3  3
2012-12-05  6  6  6
2012-12-06  7  7  7
2012-12-07  8  8  8
2012-12-08  9  9  9
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `df.head(5)` and `df.tail(5)` to get first five and last five.
Optionally you can create new data frame and `append()` head and tail:

```
new_df = df.tail(5)
new_df = new_df.append(df.head(5))
```

Answer (score 15):

Not *quite* the same question but if you just want to *show* the top / bottom 5 rows (eg with `display` in jupyter or regular `print`, there's potentially a simpler way than this if you use the [`pd.option_context`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#getting-and-setting-options) context.

```python
#make 100 3d random numbers
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3))

# sort them by their axis sum
df = df.loc[df.sum(axis=1).index]

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',10):
    print(df)
```

Outputs:

```python
           0         1         2
0  -0.649105 -0.413335  0.374872
1   3.390490  0.552708 -1.723864
2  -0.781308 -0.277342 -0.903127
3   0.433665 -1.125215 -0.290228
4  -2.028750 -0.083870 -0.094274
..       ...       ...       ...
95  0.443618 -1.473138  1.132161
96 -1.370215 -0.196425 -0.528401
97  1.062717 -0.997204 -1.666953
98  1.303512  0.699318 -0.863577
99 -0.109340 -1.330882 -1.455040

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: expanded this answer in a couple of ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311747/695804)...

Answer (score 13):

You should use both `head()` and `tail()` for this purpose. I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
df.head(5).append(df.tail(5))
```

Comment: In pandas 2.0+ `append` has been removed. `concat` is needed instead - `pd.concat([df.head(5), df.tail(5)])`

Answer (score 11):

Small simple function:

```
def ends(df, x=5):
    return df.head(x).append(df.tail(x))
```

And use like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15,6))
ends(df,2)
```

I actually use this so much, <del>I think it would be a great feature to add to pandas.</del> (No features are to be added to pandas.DataFrame core API) I add it after import like so:

```
import pandas as pd
def ends(df, x=5):
    return df.head(x).append(df.tail(x))
setattr(pd.DataFrame,'ends',ends)
```

Use like so:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15,6))
df.ends(2)
```

Comment: can you submit this to pandas git; this should be a default function

Comment: To avoid warnings- 

def ends(df, x=5):
    return pd.concat([df.head(x), df.tail(x)], axis=0)
setattr(pd.DataFrame,'ends',ends)

Answer (score 5):

In **Jupyter**, expanding on @bolster's answer, we'll create a reusable convenience function:

```
def display_n(df,n): 
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',n*2):
        display(df)
```

Then

```
display_n(df,2)
```

Returns

```
         0           1           2
0        0.167961    -0.732745   0.952637
1        -0.050742   -0.421239   0.444715
...      ...         ...         ...
98       0.085264    0.982093    -0.509356
99       -0.758963   -0.578267   -0.115865
```

(except as a nicely formatted HTML table)

when df is `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3))`

Notes:

1. Of course you could make the same thing print as text by modifying `display` to `print` above.
2. On unix-like systems, you can the autoload the above function in all notebooks by placing it in a `py` or `ipy` file in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` as described [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html?highlight=startup#startup-files).

Answer (score 1):

Associated with Linas Fx.

Defining below

```
pd.DataFrame.less = lambda df, n=10: df.head(n//2).append(df.tail(n//2))
```

then you can type only `df.less()`

It's same as type `df.head().append(df.tail())`

If you type `df.less(2)`, the result is same as `df.head(1).append(df.tail(1))`

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could add methods to pandas dataframes like this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it to just Pandas, you can use `apply()` to concatenate the head and tail:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"upper": list(ascii_uppercase), "lower": list(ascii_lowercase)}, index=range(1, 27)
)

df.apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x.head(2), x.tail(2)]))


   upper lower
1      A     a
2      B     b
25     Y     y
26     Z     z
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining @ic_fl2 and @watsonic to give the below in Jupyter:

```py
def ends_attr():
    def display_n(df,n):
        with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',n*2):
            display(df)
    # set pd.DataFrame attribute where .ends runs display_n() function
    setattr(pd.DataFrame,'ends',display_n)

ends_attr()
```

View first and last 3 rows of your df:

```py
your_df.ends(3)
```

I like this because I can copy a single function and know I have everything I need to use the ends attribute.