# select multiple rows by index in pandas if it is in a list

Tags: pandas, indexing

Similar to [Select multiple sections of rows by index in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828331/select-multiple-sections-of-rows-by-index-in-pandas), I have large dataframe, and there are a few indexes I am interested in viewing.

I have:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'B':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']},
                  index=range(10,20,))
```

and there are few indexes I want to see, `list=[12,15,10,14]`

so that I end up with:

```
    A  B
12  2  c
15  5  f
10  0  a
14  4  e
```

is there a command so that I can go:

```
df.iloc[[index isin list]]
```

as the value list is made from an earlier piece of code.

I tried:

```
df.loc[[ix]]
```

where `ix=dm.iloc[250].sort_values()[:10].index` and is `Int64Index([250, 1109, 427, 513, 678, 18, 697, 1075, 533, 739], dtype='int64')`

to no avail.

suggestions welcomed!

Comment: `df.loc[list_]` also dont name a variable as `list` since it is a builtin function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First change `list` to another name like `L`, because `list` is a reserved word in Python. Then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting by labels:

```
L=[12,15,10,14]
df = df.loc[L]
print (df)
    A  B
12  2  c
15  5  f
10  0  a
14  4  e
```

Your solution is close for select by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) function:

```
L1 = [2,5]
df = df.iloc[L1]

print (df)
    A  B
12  2  c
15  5  f
```

Comment: How do I select multiple slices, or ranges, of rows? For example first two rows together with the last row

Comment: @Nermin - Do you think `L1 = [0,1,-1]` ?

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `L1 = [a:b, c:d]`. Where `a < b < c < d`. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: @Nermin - Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504984/python-pandas-select-both-head-and-tail/42505051#42505051) ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But just curious, is there no native or pandas solution available, rather than using Numpy?

Comment: @Nermin - I think not. Exist only numpy solution.