# Dataframe slicing with two indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I got the following dataframe,df, with the `report_date` as the index:

| report_date | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-30 | 130000 |
| 2021-06-30 | 140000 |
| 2021-07-31 | 125000 |
| 2021-07-31 | 110000 |
| 2021-08-31 | 110000 |
| 2021-08-31 | 110000 |

And I want to extract 2021-06 and 2021-08 only. How could I achieve this goal?

I can just extract two individual dataframe by `df['2021-06']` and `df['2021-08']`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691050/16424700) answer your question?

Comment: Can you check `df.loc['2021-06']` or `df.loc['2021-08']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For match values is possible convert `DatetimeIndex` to months periods and test membership by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
#if necessary
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df3 = df[df.index.to_period('m').isin(pd.to_datetime(['2021-06','2021-08']).to_period('m'))]
print (df3)
              sales
report_date        
2021-06-30   130000
2021-06-30   140000
2021-08-31   110000
2021-08-31   110000
```

Or:

```
df3 = df[df.index.to_period('m').isin(pd.PeriodIndex(['2021-06','2021-08'], freq='m'))]
print (df3)
              sales
report_date        
2021-06-30   130000
2021-06-30   140000
2021-08-31   110000
2021-08-31   110000
```

Or convert values to strings `YYYY-MM` and test by strings in list:

```
df3 = df[df.index.strftime('%Y-%m').isin(['2021-06','2021-08'])]
print (df3)
              sales
report_date        
2021-06-30   130000
2021-06-30   140000
2021-08-31   110000
2021-08-31   110000
```

Comment: but I would like combine into one dataframe but not two separate dataframe

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Index(['2021-06', '2021-08'], dtype='object', name='report_date')] are in the [index]"

Comment: @Hang - what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31',
               '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31',
               '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31',
               ...
               '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31',
               '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31',
               '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='report_date', length=5146, freq=None)

Comment: @Hang - answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
df = df.reset_index()
new_df = df[(df["report_date"] == "2021-06") | (df["report_date"] == "2021-07")]
```

or using `numpy`

```
new_df = df.iloc[np.where((df.index == "2021-06") | (df.index == "2021-07"))[0], :]
```

Output -

|  | report_date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-06 | 130000 |
| 1 | 2021-06 | 140000 |
| 2 | 2021-07 | 125000 |
| 3 | 2021-07 | 110000 |

Comment: df.index == '2021-06',  df.index == '2021-07' will be False, so nothing can be shown

Comment: Is there a way that not to reset the index

Comment: @Hang Yeah the second method does that. I have tried it.

Comment: It returns a empty dataframe to me...

Comment: @Hang try, `df.loc[["2021-06", "2021-07"], :]`

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Index(['2021-06', '2021-07'], dtype='object', name='report_date')] are in the [index]"

Comment: print (df.index) = DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', ... '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2021-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='report_date', length=5146, freq=None)

Comment: @Hang can you just convert the dataframe into a dictionary and add it in the question? And try `df.loc[["2021-06-30", "2021-07-31"], :]` for the new indices.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to do that, sorry about that. You may create a dataframe similar to mine will be okay for testing.

Comment: @Hang I am using the dataframe from the question and the three methods so work.

Comment: Huh,  that's strange. However, @jezrael has already solved, you can take a look.

Comment: @Hang no problems!